# Объясните как работают sticky intent?

Tags: android-sdk

Объясните как работают sticky intent?

Я понимаю что происходит при регистрации `BroadcastReceiver`, при `sendBroadcast` и т.д.

Но вот, например, в книге есть такое пример:

```
IntentFilter batIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent battery = context.registerReceiver(null, batIntentFilter);
int status = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = ((status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING) || (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL));
```

Создается `IntentFilter`, дальше вызывается метод регистрации `BroadcastReceiver`, но вместо приемника ему передается `null`.
Ему должны передаваться `BroadcastReceiver` и `IntentFilter` для него - для регистрации.

Но, как я понял из документации, если передать `null` вернется sticky intent. И что он делает? Зачем он? Как он применяется?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Система может "выбрасывать" sticky и обычные интенты. Обычные интенты срабатывают когда произошло какое то событие, но после регистрации на это события. Sticky интент, в случае если он уже сработал, будет доставлен сразу же после регистрации на это событие, другими словами если какое то событие уже произошло, то после регистрации на него оно сразу же доставится receiver'y. Если в метод [registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) передать `null` в качестве `receiver`, то в случае со sticky сразу же будет возвращен `intent` с информацией о событии, но без последующей регистрации для него. В вашем случае [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) является sticky и поэтому вам будет сразу возвращен intent с информацией и состоянии батареи, но без регистрации на это событие.