# Что делает registerReceiver(null, intentFilter);?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Что даёт такой код?

```
registerReceiver(null, intentFilter);
```

Метод регистрирует приёмник и фильтр для него. А тут регистрируется ничего с фильтром.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420858/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-sticky-intent

Comment: Я свяжу пока вопросы. Потом один закроем. На тостере Вам ответили не то ?

Comment: Там неуверенный ответ.