# Что такое Sticky Intent?

Tags: android

Нашел объяснение на англ, но честно не совсем понял все равно когда и зачем он нужен... Я так понял, что только для того, чтоб понять когда батарея разряжена или заряжена?

На русском не нашел.

Объясните, что это и зачем нужно? Сегодня задали такой вопрос на собеседовании, а я не мог вспомнить вообще видел ли я его когда то...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420858/181119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это способ приложения реагировать на многие события, в том числе на изменение состояния батареи, произошедшие в любое время, в том числе до запуска приложения. То есть обычный широковещательный интент после отправки системой будет принят только теми приложениями, которые к этому моменту зарегистрировали приёмник этого интента. Это как крикнуть на улице, услышат вас только те прохожие, которые были рядом. Для отправки "липкого" интента больше подошёл бы термин "публикация". Он останется "висеть", пока его не сменит другой интент этого же типа. И любое приложение получит его сразу после регистрации приёмника. Это подобно вывешиванию объявления, которое прохожие могут прочитать в любой момент.